# Heroku can't find server.js

Tags: node.js, express, heroku

I'm having problems figuring out why Heroku can't find my server.js file under the 'app' folder which is where it's looking for it. I have followed the following steps more than once:
1. Deleted the existing .git folder and the existing Heroku respository.  I then init a new git respository and created a new Heroku respository and push to Heroku.  Here are my docs:

**server.js**

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const path = require('path');

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/dist'));

app.listen(process.env.PORT || 3000);

/*
PathLocationStrategy - lets Angular handle routing for sub-routes instead of the server.
 When we type in some sub-route of our application, index.html will get served
 before any other route that might get typed into the address bar.  Angular will handle any sub-routes.
*/

app.get('/*', function(req, res) {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/dist/index.html'));
});

console.log('Console listening on port 3000');
```

**Here is an image of my file structure showing server.js:**

[image]

**Here is the Heroku log:**

https://gist.github.com/c9991932e7adc3bb6298f1228482fa02.git

Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

What does your Procfile file look like?

It should be something like:

```
web: node ./src/app/server
```

and once you do that I think your paths will be wrong for your resources. If your index.html file is in dist/schoolsdropdown then

```
 __dirname + '/dist/index.html
```

would be:

```
__dirname + '../../dist/schoolsdropdown/index.html
```

Comment: Heroku says the Procfile belongs in the app root.  I don't have a Procfile, but Heroku says for most languages, a Procfile is not necessary.  It doesnt say which languages :-)  Also, what is considered the official app root, 'src' or 'app'?

Comment: I’ve always used one for express apps. It goes at the top level of your git repo